# Vue.js props object passed to children component is undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, parent-child, vue-props

I have got a parent and a child component. The parent component includes directly the child component. This child component needs some data from the parent. The parent component loads the data from a REST API.
When the children component try to do some action with the passed Data, the Browser shows the error message in log: `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`.
When I look in the Vue Developer Tool, I can see that there is an object with the userInformation...

I want to access the data object directly in the children component with the created() method. But it seems that the data passing is too slow. How can I solve this?

**My Parent:**

```
<template>
    <b-container fluid>
          <p>Parent Stuff.....</p>
          <ChildComponent :user="this.userInformation"></ChildComponent>
    </b-container>
</template>

<script>
    import ChildComponent from "@/views/ChildComponent";

    export default {
        name: "Parent",
        components: {
          ChildComponent
        },
        data() {
          return {
            userInformation: {},
          }
        },
        created() {
          this.fetchUserInformation();
        },
        methods: {
          fetchUserInformation() {
              this.axios({
                method: 'get',
                url: process.env.VUE_APP_BACKEND_USER + '/users?username=abc'
            }).then(response => {
                this.userInformation = response.data[0];
            })
          }
      }
  }
</script>
```

**My Child:**

```
<script>

export default {
  name: "ChildComponent",
  props: {
    user: {
      type: Object
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      mathStudent: false
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.decideWhichStudent();
  },
  methods: {
    decideWhichStudent() {
      if (this.user.course.name === 'Math') {
        this.mathStudent = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: did you try out `if ((this.user.course && this.user.course.name === 'Math') {`?

Comment: Now I tried this. That seems to work. Thank you. But is that the best practice? When the user object has got a lot of objects and I want to check several attributes, I have to check for every attribute?

Comment: this `if ((this.user && this.user.course.name === 'Math')` is sufficient, try to check the whole object

Comment: I tried this with the whole object at the beginning and then I get the same error as described in the original question.

Comment: modify the prop like `user: {
      type: Object,default:null
    }`

Comment: I added the `default: null` to the prop, but that makes no distinction

Comment: so keep it as suggested at beginning

Answer (score 1):

You need to use it like this:

```
<ChildComponent :user="userInformation"></ChildComponent>
```

Without the `this` keyword.

Comment: Tanks, but when I change the code as you suggested, I get the same error again.

Comment: It's probably from the browser cache, clear the browser cache and try again.

Comment: That did not do the trick. Same error message as before. I cleared Cache, restarted Chrome.

Comment: Check if the property is available in your `if` statement.

Comment: The property is available in the `if` statement, but not the underlying attributes

Comment: The nested properties `this.user.course` is available, but this not: `this.user.course.name`

Comment: You may also try `this.$nextTick(() => this.decideWhichStudent())`, in `mounted` hook of your child component.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not bring any improvement. The same error is displayed. Thanks for your trouble.